# Entire function with $f(n) = \mathrm{sign}(n)\!\cdot\!n^2$ for nonzero integer $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

To rephrase, I'm searching for an entire function with $f(n) = n^2$ and $f(-n) = -n^2$ for all positive integers $n$. I found this question on a Ph.D. qualifying exam, here (Q8)

https://math.unm.edu/sites/default/files/files/qual-exams/complex/unm_exam_201508_cmpx_qual.pdf

> Show that there exists an entire function $~f(z)~$ such that $~f(n) = n^2~$ at every positive integer
> $~n~$ and $~f(n) = −n^2~$ at every negative integer $~n.~$ How many such entire functions are there?

and I'm a bit stumped by it. Can anyone give a hint?

Greg

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.  See also the **Edit-Images** section of the article.

Comment: the existence is just general stuff about entire functions and if $f$ works than any $f+g\sin \pi z$ works for arbitrary entire $g$, so there are infinitely many such

Comment: For a concrete construction of the lowest order possible, one  notices that $h(z)=z^2\cos (2\pi z)$ satisfies $h(n)=n^2$ and then one can easily interpolate the signum function (being bounded on the reals) by a series to get an entire function with $h_1(n)$ being the signum of $n$ so $f=hh_1$ gives a concrete example of lowest order possible

Comment: Conrad, thanks for your comments. Indeed, as you say it's simple that we can create many such functions given that we have one in the first place. But would you mind fleshing out the rest of it a bit? What is the general existence theorem here? I thought maybe some infinite product but I don't know how to set it up. Also how do we find this entire function $h_1$ you mention? I think you are using some results/methods I'm not familiar with.

Comment: the general theorem is a combination of Mittag Leffler and Weierstrass (given any discrete set of points like $n$ and any Taylor polynomial $P_n$ of some order $k_n$ at $n$ - order zero meaning just the value $a_n$ - one can construct by Mittag Leffler a meromorphic function that has $P_n/(z-n)^{k_n+1}$ - eg $b_n/(z-n)$ principal part at $n$ and by Weirestrass a function that has a zero of order $k_n+1$ at $n$ - eg $\sin \pi z$ for order zero, so values - and their product is an entire function whose Taylor series starts at $n$ with the given $P_n$, so in the value case satisfies $P(n)=a_n$

Comment: The above works for any discrete set, but if the set consists of the integers and if $a_n$ is bounded (other less restrictive conditions work but it gets more complicated), one can interpolate the $a_n$ by the function $f(z)=\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi}(a_0/z+\sum_{n \ne 0}(-1)^na_n(\frac{1}{z-n}-\frac{1}{n})+c)$ which is easily proven entire and $f(n)=a_n$; in general $f$ above is the "simplest" one we can get

Comment: Beautiful!! I think I get it now. I think that in this special case we can even just avoid the major theorems, by just writing down the function. I get $$f(z) = \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi} ( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z-n) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{z+n)).$$ Those sums converge for all $z$ unless $z$ is a pole, as can be seen by pairing successive terms. Thank you!!

Comment: The above mimics the general proof as Mittag Leffler is proven in a similar way with a construction of the same type, but here the proof is immediate indeed